# React's useState leak

Tags: memory-leaks, react-hooks, garbage-collection, setstate

I'm investigating a memory leak I observed in `useState`. I don't think it's a general problem, but it definitely happens under some conditions and they are not clear to me at all.

Conceptually, I'm allocating big strings (100MB, just to have an easy number to track in the profiler) and setting them into a React state hook. The crux of the question is that depending on both how the strings are created and how are set into the state, there are ever more allocations for every new string without being garbage-collected, unless the component actually unmounts.

I've created a tiny [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-leak-ypcxh?file=/src/App.js) project to [reproduce](https://ypcxh.csb.app/) the issue (I'd encourage you to test it yourself if your are curious, it's actually fun to play around with variants of this experiment :P), but I'm just going to document what I observe.

### Leaker

Given:

```
const length = 100000000;
function getBuffer() {
  return new Array(length).join("*");
}

function Leaker() {
  const [, setState] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState(getBuffer())}>leak</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The behaviour when clicking the button is the following (numbers are the consecutive button clicks):

1. Around ~15kb are allocated (interesting! I would actually expect 100MB).
2. 200MB are allocated: Now we are talking. In the memory snapshot, I see one string instance owned by the `memoizedState` object, and another one owned by an object which is not there anymore (yet, is not garbage collected, even when asking the browser to do it through the developer tools).
3. 100MB are allocated: A new instance of the string is owned by the properties `action` and `eagerState`, of an object which seems to be in a linked list referenced by its `next` property (I think this is how `useState` is implemented, although I don't know the details).
4. yet another 100MB are allocated: All previous allocations remain there, no garbage collection even if the browser is asked to so.
5. yet another 100MB allocated: I guess you see the pattern... I can actually keep going until the tab crashes with `SIGILL`.

All allocated memory gets garbage-collected though, after then `Leaker` component is unmounted.

[image: Leaker memory profile]

But now, stay tuned because there are some interesting details yet to come.

### NonLeaker

If the implementation of the component was instead:

```
function NonLeaker() {
  const [, setState] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setState({
            buffer: getBuffer()
          })
        }
      >
        not leak
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Namely, instead of setting the string directly into the state we set an object with a property containing the string, the same procedure above doesn't cause any leak whatsoever. Instead:

1. Around ~15kb are allocated.
2. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
3. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
4. ...etc, good job!

[image: NonLeaker memory profile]

### Leaker variant

And yet! Consider the following implementation of `getBuffer` instead:

```
const length = 100000000;
let i = 0;
function getBuffer() {
  return `${i++}${new Array(length).join("*")}`;
}
```

So, we have changed how the string is created (because now we are concatenating two strings... I imagine this *could* already make a difference), and every new string will be slightly different (and certainly, the length of the string itself will increase as the number grows).

Then the behaviour of `NonLeaker` is still the same, but `Leaker` exhibits the following:

1. Around ~15kb are allocated.
2. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
3. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
4. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
5. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
6. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
7. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
8. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
9. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
10. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
11. Around ~15kb are allocated, and the previous allocation gets garbage-collected.
12. 200MB are allocated.
13. 100MB are allocated, and the previous 100MB garbage-collected.
14. 100MB are allocated, and the previous 100MB garbage-collected.
15. ...etc, good job!

From that point onwards, there's always the last 200MB which keep allocated, and anything older gets properly deallocated (I don't know the internals of React, but it isn't unreasonable that it keeps current and previous states for whatever reason).

[image: Leaker variant memory profile]

Keep in mind that for this difference in behaviour we have just changed how the string was created, so it seems clear to me that there is some interdependency between the implementation of React's `useState` and the way how objects are created, so that under some circumstances a memory leak can be caused.

### Closing thoughts

Of course, this is a kind of laboratory setup, but the reason I started to investigate this possible leak is because I'm working on an application where we suddenly experienced a massive increase in memory usage after a refactoring, and I'm considering that by changing how objects are being allocated, some components might be exhibiting the same behaviour observed in `Leaker`.

A question that remains in my head (and makes me slightly close my eyes as in "wait a second, there's something spooky here...") is, why I don't see the allocation of 100MB in the `NonLeaker` component? The data is actually there because I tried to reference it after setting the state and I can definitely use the string, print it, etc. Is there something I'm overlooking about the memory profiler? Or is the Javascript engine playing some tricks to save memory for us? (I could imagine for example, that given that the string is just a sequence of repeated characters, it could be easily stored as "X concatenations of string Y", instead of a single huge string Y).

In general, does anyone here in the community have an idea on what could be going on? Or some existing reference materials (easier than jumping into React's source code) that could point me in the right direction?

BTW., I have been using Chrome (version `92.0.4515.107`) to profile the memory (also because it's the main browser to be supported in the project of my client) but I also observed the same leak in Firefox just testing out of curiosity.

Phew, **thanks a lot!** This was a long one... :D

---